# Convert SQL query to JPQL query - sum number of attributes with a specific text value

Tags: mysql, sql, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

My SQL query is

```
SELECT cust.*, sum(ord.status="Pending") as pendingOrderCount, sum(ord.status="Completed") as completedOrderCount
FROM customer cust
LEFT JOIN item_order ord ON ord.customer_id = cust.id 
WHERE cust.tenant_id = 1
GROUP BY cust.id
```

This query works in MySql Workbench

So essentially I want to get all of the customer's attributes, then add two more aliases, the number of completed orders is the number of orders from that customer where order.status is "Complete" and the number of pending orders per customer

In my Spring Boot JPA repository class, I'm trying to recreate this query using JPQL. This is my attempt:

```
@Query("select cust, sum(ord.status = 'Completed') as completedOrders, sum(ord.status = 'Pending') as pendingOrders from item_order ord LEFT JOIN ord.customer where customer id = 1)
```

I know this is incorrect, my IDE is displaying syntax errors at
ord.status = 'Completed'
and
ord.status = 'Pending'

At the equals sign. I've been looking at JPQL documentation but haven't found any example where the sum of an attribute with a given value is obtained, so could use some help with that please

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: The query has been sanitized, using a reserved keyword was a mistake.
I've spent several hours reading upon JPA and JPQL's various online resources, but I'm new to JPA and JPQL and haven't found an answer or example similar to my use case.
According to https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/from#LEFT_OUTER_JOIN
In JPQL,it seems that  LEFT JOIN may not use an ON clause.

Comment: Above comment was in response to now deleted comments by Stawberry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered how to count the number of attributes conditionally depending on their status in JPQL

```
sum(case when ord.status = 'Completed' then 1 else 0 end) as completedOrders, sum(case when ord.status = 'Pending' then 1 else 0 end) as pendingOrders
```